# Knockout ViewModel Update

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, knockout.js

I am new to Knockout and I am trying to update my ViewModel from an ajax call. 
 This is what I have right now: 
**LoanDeductions.js**

```
var deductionLine = function (deductionID, deductionName, amount) {
    self = this;
    self.deductionID = ko.observable(deductionID);
    self.deductionName = ko.observable(deductionName);
    self.amount = ko.observable(amount);
};

function LoanDeductions(deductions) {
    var self = this;
    self.loanDeductions = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(deductions, function (deduction) {
        return new deductionLine(deduction.deductionID, deduction.deductionName, deduction.amount)
    }));

    // Operationss
    self.removeLine = function (line) { self.loanDeductions.remove(line) };
};
```

and this is my scripts in my view:

```
    @section scripts
    {
        <script src="~/Scripts/koModel/LoanDeductions.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
           var updateValues = function () {
               $.ajax({
               'url': '@Url.Action("UpdateDeductionValues","LoanApp")',
               'data': { amount: $('.LoanAmount').val() },
               'success': function (result) {// update viewmodel scripts here}
            });
            var viewModel = new LoanDeductions(@Html.Raw(Model.CRefLoansDeductions2.ToJson()));
            $(document).ready(function () {
                ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
                $('.datepicker').datepicker();
                $('.LoanAmount').change(function () {
                   updateValues();
                };
            });
        });
    </script>
    }
```

So, in my view, I have a dropdown list with class name "LoanAmount" which when value is changed, it will perform an ajax call, send the selected loanAmount value to the server, recompute the deduction amounts, **then the server returns a jsonresult that looks like this**:

```
"[{\"deductionID\":1,\"deductionName\":\"Loan Redemption Fee\",\"amount\":53.10},{\"deductionID\":2,\"deductionName\":\"Document Stamp\",\"amount\":9.00}]"
```

Now what I wanted to do is use this json data as my new viewModel. 
Can anyone show me the way how to do this, please note that I manually mapped my viewmodel and didn't used the ko mapping plugin. 
Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you, more power!

 
**EDIT (in response to Fabio)**

```
function updateData() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("UpdateDeductionValues","LoanApp")',
            data: { amount: self.selectedLoanAmount() },
            success: function (deductions) {
                //load your array with ko.utils.arrayMap
                ko.utils.arrayMap(deductions, function (deduction) {
                return new deductionLine(deduction.deductionID, deduction.deductionName, deduction.amount)
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure If I understood your problem, but if you want to change model values outside of the class, you need to do something like this:

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var viewModel = new LoanDeductions(@Html.Raw(Model.CRefLoansDeductions2.ToJson()));
              ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

            $('.datepicker').datepicker();

            function updateValues() {
                //do you ajax call
                //update the model using viewModel.loanDeductions(newItens);
            };

            $('.LoanAmount').change(function () {
               updateValues();
            };
        });
```

EDIT 1 - Just to show how to use knockout without jquery.change

```
function LoadDeductions() {
     //declare you properties
      var self = this;
      self.loanAmount = ko.observable('initialvalueofloanamount');
      self.loanDeductions = ko.observableArray();

     //create a function to update you observablearray
     function updateData() {
        $.ajax({
           url: '@Url.Content('yourActionhere')' or '@Url.Action('a', 'b')',
           data: { amount: self.loadAmount() },
           success: function (deductions) {
              //load your array with ko.utils.arrayMap
           }
        });
     }

     //everytime that loanAmount changes, update the array
     self.loanAmount.subscribe(function () {
        updateData();
     });

     //update values initializing
     updateData();

};

$(function() {
    ko.applyBindings(new LoadDeductions());
});
```

Bind the select in the HTML

```
<select data-bind="value: loanAmount"></select>
```

EDIT 2 - To your second problem

```
function updateData() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/LoanApp/UpdateDeductionValues', //try to write the url like this
        data: { amount: self.selectedLoanAmount() },
        success: function (deductions) {
            //load your array with ko.utils.arrayMap
            self.loanDeductions(ko.utils.arrayMap(deductions, function (deduction) {
                 return new deductionLine(deduction.deductionID, deduction.deductionName, deduction.amount)
            }));
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: hi thanks, thats what I am trying to do, my real problem though is the part where you say //update the model using viewModel.loanDeductions(newItens); can you elaborate how to do this, because this is what I do not know

Comment: just call viewModel.loadDeductions(NewArrayHereAsParameter); does that work? it should recreate the observablearray

Comment: Hi, i tried it but i have a console error Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "text: function (){return deductionName }"
Message: deductionName is not defined and it messed up my views not displaying any bind values

Comment: Try to not put the json inside your javascript, load it as ajax request instead

Comment: Hi fabio I think I am getting closer but can you take a look at what I did (see my edited post at the bottom) and see what I am doing wrong specially at the URL part. Because I get another error in the console: POST http://localhost:4962/LoanApp/CreateLoanApp/@Url.Content(%22~/LoanApp/UpdateDeductionValues%22) 404 (Not Found)

Comment: also if I reloaded my array correctly using ko.utils.arrayMap

Comment: I apologize I am really beginner in web development, I really appreciate your effort in helping me

Comment: I have worked my way for the URL part, my problem now is the //load your array with ko.utils.arrayMap part, can you teach me how to do it based on my model

Comment: you need to call the ko.utils.arrayMap inside the observableArray, like this: self.loanDeductions( ko.utils.arrayMap(...)  )

Comment: Hey man.. :) I am so happy right now its working now. Thaaaaank you so much Fabio, you're the best. I can sleep with smile on my face tonight. Thank you again man.

Answer (score 0):

Your success handler should look like this.

```
function(result){
  self.loanDeductions(result);
}
```

Unless you are trying to append in which case it would be

```
  self.loanDeductions(self.loanDeductions().concat(result));
```